# jw player 5 share button on the player

Tags: embed, share, jwplayer

We building video sharing site using jw player 5,

and struggling here

**example 1:**

```
            'backcolor': "{/literal}{$smarty.const._BGCOLOR}{literal}",
            'frontcolor': "{/literal}{$smarty.const._TIMECOLOR}{literal}",
            'screencolor': "000000",
            'repeat': "false",
            'logo': "{/literal}{$smarty.const._WATERMARKURL}{literal}",
            'linktarget': "_blank",
            'link': "{/literal}{$smarty.const._WATERMARKLINK}{literal}",
            'image': "{/literal}{$video_data.preview_image}{literal}",
            'sharing-3': {
            'link': '{/literal}{$video_data.video_href}{literal}',
            'code': encodeURIComponent('{/literal}{$embedcode}{literal}')
            }
```

**And how to add this part into example 2:**

```
                'sharing-3': {
                'link': '{/literal}{$video_data.video_href}{literal}',
                'code': encodeURIComponent('{/literal}{$embedcode}{literal}')
                }
```

**example 2:**

```
    $jw_flashvars .= '&config='. urlencode(_URL ."/players/jwplayer5/jwembed.xml"); // @since v2.2
    $jw_flashvars .= '&backcolor='. _BGCOLOR;
    $jw_flashvars .= '&frontcolor='. _TIMECOLOR;
    $jw_flashvars .= '&screencolor=000000';
    $jw_flashvars .= '&bufferlength=5'; 
    $jw_flashvars .= '&plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-2';
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: JW Player 5 is obsolete, and now unsupported. The current version is 6.10 (that's "six-point-ten," the tenth version of JW6). No sense struggling with deprecated software.

Comment: Just i like to add below code in to Example:2                                   plugins: {
 "sharing-3": {
 code: "",
 link: ""
 }
 },